# Existence of a sequence such that random variables converge

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Is there a possibility to construct a sequence which includes no $0$ values and is finite, so that random variables $X_1, X_2,...$ multiplied with this sequence converge almost surely?

My first idea was constructional, applying Chebyshev's inequality. However, this was not very successful since my constructed sequence would also have some $0$-values.

Hence, my next thought was arguing with the Tail-Sigma Algebra (lets call it $T$) generated by $X_1, X_2,...$. Let $a_n$ be the desired sequence. However, since $\limsup X_n a_n$ belongs to $T$ (Not 100 % sure?), $P(X_n a_n = 0 \mbox{ infinitely often}) \in \{0,1\}$.

Thanks in advance for your tips, and thought-provoking impulses!

Comment: Are $X_i$'s bounded almost surely? If yes, then you can choose $c_n \sim 1/n$.

Comment: Is it possible to assume the boundedness? I don't have any further properties given... So I do not really now if I can assume that Xi does not take the value $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if we do not assume that $|X_n| < \infty$ a.s. then this is false. For an extreme case just consider the example of $X_i(\omega) = \infty$ for all $i$ and all $\omega$. It is clear that no such sequence exists since in this case $X_i c_i = \infty$ for any positive real number $c_i$.

If $|X_n| < \infty$ a.s. then by writing
$$0 = \mathbb{P}(|X_n| = \infty) = \lim_{K \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq K)$$
we see that for each $n$ there is a $K(n)$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq K(n)) \leq 2^{-n}$. Let $c_n = 2^{-n}K(n)^{-1}$ and let $A_n$ be the event $\{|X_n| < K(n)\}$. Notice that by construction, we have $\mathbb{P}(A_n) \geq 1 - 2^{-n}$. Finally, let
$$A = \bigcup_{j \geq 0} \bigcap_{n \geq j} A_n.$$

I claim that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ and that for $\omega \in A$, $X_n(\omega)c_n \to 0$. For the latter fact, notice that if $\omega \in A$ then there is a $j(\omega)$ such that for $n \geq j(\omega)$, $|X_n(\omega)| < K(n)$. This implies that for $n \geq j(\omega)$ we have that $|X_n(\omega)c_n| \leq 2^{-n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

It remains to see that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$. For this, write
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A) =& 1 - \mathbb{P}\left ( \bigcap_{j \geq 0} \bigcup_{n \geq j} A_n^c \right)
\\ \geq& 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n \geq k} A_n^c \right) \text{ for any fixed } k
\\
\geq& 1- \sum_{n \geq k} 2^{-n}
\\ =& 1- 2^{-k+1}
\end{align*}

Since $k$ was arbitrary, by sending $k \to \infty$ we see that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ as desired.